# Missing docker 18.09.10 files on repository

Tags: centos, docker

As stated in [Docker Engine Release Notes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#180910), the 18.09.10 version was released on 2019-10-08.

I'm trying to install the respective Docker CE on CentOS, but the `.rpm` files are not available at the [CentOS 7 repo](https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/). I can't even find a [tag/release for 18.09.10](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v18.09.10) on docker-ce GitHub.

The files were not built or I'm missing something? As per the releases page, the version should exist:

> Docker Engine - Enterprise builds upon the corresponding Docker Engine
>   - Community that it references...

The 19.03.3 (released on the same day) is correctly available at CentOS repository and Github release.

*PS: I created an issue here ([#824](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/824)), but I'm also asking here to see if anyone else can help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker CE is only updated for about a month after the next major release comes out (there may be rare exceptions). After that, only the latest release receives patches. So after 19.03 was released, patches for 18.09 would stop after roughly a month. For customers that needed more support of older releases, there's Docker Enterprise which continues patching for older releases for something like 1 year.

Therefore you won't see a tag on docker-ce/releases, and won't find a rpm in the docker-ce repo. But you will see release notes for Docker Enterprise.